# React Native Webview only loads once

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, react-native-webview

I have a drawer navigator sidebar in my react native app, one of the options in the sidebar takes users to a page where a WebView will load up a website.

The WebView works fine the first time, but when i exit the WebView and try to load it again through the sidebar, it will not load at all.

Console logging the nativeEvent from onLoadProgress  also works the first time, but after that no logs are found,

The WebView just wouldn't load anymore after the first time.

```
 const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);

 `const navChange= (navState: any) => {
    console.log(navState.nativeEvent)
    if (navState.nativeEvent.url.includes('main-page')) {
        setModalVisible(false);
        navigation.navigate('MainPage');
        }
    };

<Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible} 
    >
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.body}>
                <WebView 
                    key={new Date().getTime()} 
                    source={{ uri: 'https://my-website-port/my-website' }} 
                    onLoadProgress={navChange}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true} 
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    </Modal>`
```

I have tried using key, and many more options from the internet, but none has worked so far.

I want the WebView in my drawer navigator to load successfully everytime.

Comment: Have you tried using "navigation.push('page')" instead of "navigation.navigate('page')"?

Comment: I tried it, but closing the WebView brought me to a blank page instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it's because my "modalVisible" state is set to false after I exit the WebView and it still remains false even after that (it doesn't set itself to true when the page is rendered). This only occurs if my page is in the Drawer Navigation/Sidebar. If the WebView is in the normal stack navigation it works fine, the "modalVisible" will always set to true initially.

So my solution was to set "modalVisible" to "true" everytime the page is in focused, I put it on top of my existing code like so :

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFocused) {
            setModalVisible(true);
        } 
    }, [isFocused]);
```